# How to loop through one table and then Insert into another based on multiple IF ELSE

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table like below with 2 columns. This table already is populated with all the data I need.

Table 1

```
ID (int)    TYPE  (string)
```

The other table looks like this and it's empty

Table 2

```
ID (int)     Somedetail (int)
```

I need to loop through Table 1 and then insert into Table 2 if TYPE = 'string' 
for each row and I have about 5 different string I need to test against.

INSERT WILL BE insert into Table 2 (ID, int). I will provide the int value based on if TYPE = 'string' matches or not.

This is what I have currently.
SELECT ID, TYPE
FROM TABLE1
IF(ID = 'STRING1')
INSERT INTO TABLE2...
ELSE IF (ID = 'STRING2')
INSERT INTO

and so on

Comment: show some data please and expected output

Comment: There is no output. I just need to insert into TABLE 2.

Comment: Pretty unclear what you want.. Maybe `CASE WHEN Type = x THEN 1 WHEN Type = y THEN 2...etc`.  Provide some sample data and desired output for a better answer.

Comment: @Tex The output would be what you want table 2 to look like after the insert...

Comment: I added a pseudo query I have in mind, That should make it clear.

Comment: Table 2 will have ID from Table 1 and an int based on if else.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are basically looking for an `INSERT INTO SELECT` statement (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/insert-transact-sql). In your case this would take the form:

```
INSERT INTO Table2
SELECT 
    id, 
    CASE 
        WHEN type = 'string1' THEN intvalue1
        WHEN type = 'string2' THEN intvalue2
        WHEN type = 'string3' THEN intvalue3
        WHEN type = 'string4' THEN intvalue4
        WHEN type = 'string5' THEN intvalue5
        END
FROM Table1
WHERE type IN ('string1', 'string2', 'string3', 'string4', 'string5');
```

Where we just take the results of that SELECT statement and shove it into Table2 with the `INSERT INTO`.

Comment: Thank you. Works like a charm.

Answer (score 0):

Fairly positive you want to use `CASE` based on your comments.  You'll have to fill in the strings and the ints that you want, but here is the shell:

```
INSERT INTO Table2 (ID, Somedetail)
SELECT ID,
       CASE WHEN Type = 'string1' THEN 1,
            WHEN Type = 'string2' THEN 2,
            etc...
       END as Somedetail
FROM Table1
```

Comment: Thank you. I'll try yours too.